# Burpsuite and Tor browser problem

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks, web-proxy

I set http / https proxy as 127.0.0.1 / 8080 in tor browser and set socks proxy as 127.0.0.1 / 9150 in burpsuite. But whenever i click 'connect' in tb, it doesn't work. what is wrong???

OS : win 10 pro 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Check your tb logs - the Tor Browser Bundle has it's own tor supplied with it and until it's 100% bootstrapped - neither a side app(burpsuite in your case) nor the tb itself will not work. The Tb's Tor log has a full answer for your problem, it's nowhere else to look